# onkeydown event работает со второго символа

Tags: javascript

есть `input` с евентом:

```
t.onkeydown = function() {
                var str = this.value;
                if(~str.indexOf("123")){
                    t.value = "";
                }       
             }
```

Евент отрабатывает только после нажатия второй клавиши. Почему не после первой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обработка нажатия происходит в несколько событий (их достаточно много).
`keydown` происходит перед вставкой символа. Т. е. когда происходит это событие, `input` выглядит ещё по-старому. Либо используйте что-то более позднее (`keypress`, к примеру), либо [более адекватные средства](https://learn.javascript.ru/events-change) - `input`.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что на **keydown** эвенте не печатается символ. Ловите события: **change**, **input**.

**keydown** отрабатывает исключительно на момент нажатия клавиши.

**keyup** на поднятии.

**input** при вводе

**change** при изменении формы